# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j=0$, and the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \sum_{j=1}^n ja_j$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is the detailed problem statement.

> Let {$a_n$} be a sequence of non-negative terms such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

> (i) Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j=0$.

Put $\sum a_n=A$.
For this part, I just decompose the given sequence into multiple pieces:

$\frac{1}{n}${$a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+na_n$}$=\frac{1}{n}${$(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n)+a_2+2a_3+3a_4+\cdots+(n-1)a_n$}

The similar process decomposes the sequence over and over. If I take limit, then I'll get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{C}{n}=0$ where $C$ is some constant. I know this is not a complete solution yet, but I'd like to know if I'm on the right track and how to rigorously write this proof.

> (ii) Determine the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j$ and compute its sum in case it is convergent.

For this part, I just tried to list up some elements and grouped them as follows:

$\frac{1}{2}a_1+\frac{1}{6}(a_1+2a_2)+\frac{1}{12}(a_1+2a_2+3a_3)+\frac{1}{20}(a_1+2a_2+3a_3+4a_4)+\cdots=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\cdots)a_1+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots)a_2+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{20}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots)a_3+\cdots$

In this way, I think I can see this sequence converges because $\sum_{j=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^j=1$ and coefficients of each $a_k$ is less than this sequence. However, I cannot compute the sum. I don't even know if I can compute the sum with this approach.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238152).

Comment: Indeed, so why duplicate the answer?

Answer (score 3):

- (i) is a special case of [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma): $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{c_n}\sum_{j=1}^n c_j a_j=0$ for any nondecreasing sequence $(c_n)$ of positive numbers with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n=\infty$. See the link for a proof (using summation by parts).
- (ii) follows easily from (i) and the following observation: $$\small\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n(n+1)}\sum_{j=1}^n ja_j}=\sum_{j=1}^N ja_j\sum_{n=j}^N\frac1{n(n+1)}=\sum_{j=1}^N ja_j\left(\frac1j-\frac1{N+1}\right)\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^N a_j-\frac1{N+1}\sum_{j=1}^N ja_j}.$$

Comment: (+1) However, for a more elementary solution of (i), see [If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ converges then $\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nka_k\to0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584330). Note also that neither (i) nor (ii) need $a_n\ge0.$